Passing parameters into XSLT 2.0 transformation using Python and saxonche
After successful "pip install saxonche" Python should perform XSLT2.0-tranformations. The following xslt script though announces and refers also to two parameters, that would have to be passed through the Python script, but are not even metioned in the provided code hereafter. Obvious question: How to - if possible- modify the following Python-script, so two variables e.g. my_param1='value1' and my_param2='value2' could successfuly be refered to, like expressed in the xslt code? Answers are highly appreciated.
Python:
from saxonche import *

output_file = 'output.html'

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:

  print(proc.version)
  try:
      xsltproc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()
      document = proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name='input.xml')
      executable = xsltproc.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_file="xslt2.xsl")

      output = executable.transform_to_string(xdm_node=document)
      
      print(output)
          
      with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
          f.write(output.encode('utf-8'))
        
  
  except PySaxonApiError as err:
              print('Error during function call', err)
              

XSLT:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="my_param1" />
    <xsl:param name="my_param2" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                       <div>
              <xsl:value-of select="root/data" />
              <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="$my_param1" /> 
              <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="$my_param2" /> 
              </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <data>Hello world!</data>
</root>

Actual (rendered HTML):
Hello world! | |

Wanted (rendered HTML):
Hello world! | value1 | value2


Python v3.12.4
Official Saxonica python package for the SaxonC-HE 12.5.0 processor: for XSLT 3.0, XQuery 3.1, XPath 3.1 and XML Schema processing.
Win10


Saxon 12 is an XSLT 3 processor (like any Saxon version since 9.8) so you might as well use version="3.0" in your XSLT code. That's just a comment in general, not related to your Python API usage question.

Hi Boris! Since you have an answer which "works perfectly", you should formally accept it by clicking the ✔ next to it

Since you're just passing in strings, you can use executable.set_parameter() to pass in a string value using proc.make_string_value()...
executable.set_parameter('my_param1', proc.make_string_value('value1'))
executable.set_parameter('my_param2', proc.make_string_value('value2'))

Full example...
from saxonche import *

output_file = 'output.html'

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    print(proc.version)
    try:
        xsltproc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()
        document = proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name='input.xml')
        executable = xsltproc.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_file="xslt2.xsl")

        # Set params
        executable.set_parameter('my_param1', proc.make_string_value('value1'))
        executable.set_parameter('my_param2', proc.make_string_value('value2'))

        output = executable.transform_to_string(xdm_node=document)

        print(output)

        with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(output.encode('utf-8'))

    except PySaxonApiError as err:
        print('Error during function call', err)


Works perfectly. Thank you very very much!

@BorisHoeller - You're very welcome. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark next to it. (See here.)
